# Compile c code with float instead of double

Tags: gcc, floating-point

I have a lengthy numeric integration scheme written in C. I'd like to test my algorithm in floating point precision. Is there a way to tell gcc to demote every occurrence of `double` to `float` in the entire program?

Comment: Does adding `#define double float` in your source work for you? Unfortunatley, `-Ddouble=float` does not work because it'd affect system headers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't safely do this without modifying your source code, but that shouldn't be terribly difficult to do.

Using the preprocessor to force the keyword `double` in your program to be treated as `float` is a bad idea; it will make your program difficult to read, and if you happen to use `long double` anywhere it would be treated as `long float`, which is a syntax error.

As [stix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24688943/827263) suggests, you can add a `typedef`, either at the top of your program (if it's a single source file) or in some header that's `#include`ed by all the relevant source files:

```
typedef double real; /* or pick a different name */
```

Then go through your source code and change each occurrence of `double` to `real`. (Be careful about doing a blind global search-and-replace.)

Make sure that the program still compiles, runs, and behaves the same way after this change. Then you can change the typedef to:

```
 typedef float real;
```

and recompile to use `float` rather than `double`.

It's not *quite* that simple, though. If you're using functions declared in `<math.h>`, you'll want to use the right function for whatever floating-point type you're using; for example, `sqrt()` is for `double`, `sqrtf()` is for `float`, and `sqrtl()` is for `long double`.

If your compiler supports it, you might use the `<tgmath.h>` header, which defines *type-generic macros* corresponding to the math functions from `<math.h>`. If you use `<tgmath.h>`, then `sqrt(x)` will resolve to call the correct square root function depending on the type of the argument. It was introduced in the 1999 edition of the ISO C standard, so availability shouldn't be a problem.

Another possible issue (thanks to Kevin Thibedeau for pointing it out) is that unsuffixed floating-point constants are of type `double`. If a `float` object appears along with a `double` constant in an expression, for example `f + 1.0`, there's likely to be an implicit `float`-to-`double` conversion. Appending `f` or `F` to a floating constant will specify that it's of type `float`.

Comment: Hm. Thanks for the answer. I guess I could write a simple `sed` script to replace all occurrence of `double`, `sqrt()`, etc.

Comment: This still doesn't address floating point literals which are of type `double`. By default, generated code will convert `float` operands of expressions containing `double` literals to `double` at runtime. This happens in software if your hardware doesn't support `double`. You have to either explicitly add the 'f' specifier or use a compiler option like GCC's -fsingle-precision-constant. The warning -Wdouble-promotion will notify you where these literals are.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef double float;
```

Before any doubles that you want to replace should work, however be warned it may confuse some external libraries.

In the future, the best approach is to define your own float type:

```
#ifdef USE_FLOATS
    typedef float MyFloatType; 
#else 
    typedef double MyFloatType;
#endif
```

Or use templates, which has the added benefit of allowing you to change the code at runtime to use one or the other.

Comment: GCC (4.9.0 on Mac OS X 10.9.4) doesn't like that: `x.c:1:16: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers` where `x.c` contains the single line `typedef double float;`.  There's a second error too, but that's mainly a consequence of the first.

Comment: `typedef double float;` is a syntax error. A typedef name must be an identifier; `float` is a keyword. And templates are not a useful suggestion unless the OP is willing to switch languages from C to C++.