# C++ avoid type conversion warning with typedef

Tags: c++, type-conversion, typedef

I am using `typedef float engtype` and `typedef double engtype` to quickly change between `float` and `double` for some testing.  When I did this for example

```
engtype rmwt = 20.75;
engtype Rgas = 8314.28 / rmwt;
```

The compiler complains of possible data loss or truncation to convert from `double` to `engtype`.  In order to make that warning go away I did this

```
engtype rmwt = 20.75;
engtype Rgas = static_cast<engtype>(8314.28) / rmwt;
```

This seems a little ridiculous.  I googled for a way to make it default to `engtype` but didn't find anything.  Is this usage of `typedef` incorrect?  How should I deal with the warnings?  I understand I can just ignore them but there should be a "correct" way to clear them.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: wanted to know are you not getting compilation error ?

Comment: The compiler is MSVS 2013.  It's not an error the code runs fine.  Just gives a bunch of warnings.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688911/compile-c-code-with-float-instead-of-double

Comment: This is a slightly paranoid warning, you can either put in some code gymnastics as you have, or turn off that warning.

Comment: So I tested this with g++ 4.3.4 and icc 12.1.0 on SUSE Linux and neither of them complained about it.  I guess this is Microsoft's way of messing with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change what `8314.28` means : it's a `double`, period.

What you *can* do is complete your typedef with an associated user-defined literal :

```
engtype operator ""_eng (long double d) {
    // Add a cast here if the compiler still complains
    return d;
}
```

Obtaining :

```
auto rmwt = 20.75_eng;
auto Rgas = 8314.28_eng / rmwt;
```

Comment: I like this idea but VS 2013 does not support it.  Was there a way to did it before C++11?

Comment: @Matt unfortunately not. Maybe you can get something not too ugly with an inline function `inline engtype eng(long double d);`.

Answer (score 1):

Your constants are doubles, which is why it complains when converting to a float. If you make them floats:

engtype rmwt = 20.75F;

Then it's converting a float to a double, or a float to a float, and the compiler won't complain either way.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of typedef is correct. To deal with warnings, you have to use static_cast(NUMBER).

Answer (score 0):

To initialize a float value you must use "f" suffix
So for example

```
auto pi = 3.14 ;      // pi type is double in this case
```

To assign float value u should use f suffix

```
auto pi = 3.14f;         // pi type is deduced to float
```

So when ur changing the typdef you are assigning double value to a float type.