# How to make float behave as double?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Is there some compiler flag in gcc to consider floats as doubles ?
I tried

```
#define float double
```

but it creates havoc in many headers and compilation fails stating

```
ublic/sdk/inc/crt/float.h:5:40: fatal error: ../include/double.h: No such file or directory
At that line it was including float
```

I then tried doing

```
  typedef float double;
```

but it fails saying

```
 error: multiple types in one declaration
```

I am looking at some compiler flag which can do this for me.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile c code with float instead of double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688911/compile-c-code-with-float-instead-of-double)

Comment: usually the best way to handle situations like this, is to have used an alias all the way from the beginning, such as `MyFloat`

Comment: What is the underlying problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: What do you expect to happen to existing functions like `std::sin(float)`? They're not magically changing to calculate the correct number of bits.

Answer (score 9):

There is no such thing. That's why you use different types. What you could do is replace " float " by " double " in your source code.

Comment: you also need to replace literals like `1.23f` to `1.23`

Comment: You're right! For that you probably need to use regex and some appropriate refactor tool.